# KVM port forward to guest (iptables) - only partial internet access?

Tags: iptables, kvm

I am quite new to KVM and read a lot of threads here, but neither one was helpful in my case.

I am having a guest on a KVM host and want to forward port 80 from the host to port 80 in the guest. I did this with iptables:

```
Guest_name=theguest
Guest_ipaddr=192.168.122.43
Host_port=( '80' )
Guest_port=( '80' )
length=$(( ${#Host_port[@]} - 1 ))
if [ "${1}" = "${Guest_name}" ]; then
   if [ "${2}" = "stopped" -o "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
       for i in `seq 0 $length`; do
               iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport ${Host_port[$i]} -j DNAT --to ${Guest_ipaddr}:${Guest_port[$i]}
               iptables -D FORWARD -d ${Guest_ipaddr}/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport ${Guest_port[$i]} -j ACCEPT
       done
   fi
   if [ "${2}" = "start" -o "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
       for i in `seq 0 $length`; do
               iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport ${Host_port[$i]} -j DNAT --to ${Guest_ipaddr}:${Guest_port[$i]}
               iptables -I FORWARD -d ${Guest_ipaddr}/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport ${Guest_port[$i]} -j ACCEPT
       done
   fi
fi
```

Overall this works, but not always. http request to the apache are working, so the rules seem to be correct. If I do a wget request to a http address, nothing happens. If I do a wget request to a ftp address (with --user=theusername --password=thepassword), it works.

The biggest problem: apt-get update is not working. All it does is:

```
0% [Verbindung mit de.archive.ubuntu.com (141.30.13.20)] [Verbindung mit security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)]
```

Only Ctrl-C helps at this stage.

The network in the KVM xml file is configured like this:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <source network="default"/>
  <mac address='themacaddress'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot in advance!